# Why Qt QML doesn't properly bind properties?

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

It's very weird because I use almost the same pattern in another QML file and it works correctly! I'm sure I'm not reassigning value anywhere (the only thing I know that can make property static)!
I have something like this (it's a simplified example and probably works as expected):

```
Item {
    property bool isExpanded: false
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            isExpanded = !isExpanded
            console.log(isExpanded)
            console.log(myId.visible)
        }
    }
    MyCustomItem {
        id: myId
        visible: isExpanded
        // other stuff
    }
}
```

`IsExpanded` changes after I click but `Item` visibility always stays the same! And I have many other properties for my item (for example `height: isExpanded ? someval : 0`) which doesn't change too! It sort of works if I always change everything manually but whats the point then? And in another QML I use a similar pattern and there it works!

**BUT!** If I put, for example `onDoubleClicked`/another button press:
`myId.visible = Qt.binding(function() {return isExpanded})`
it works as it should! So, for some unknown reason it doesn't 'bind' them when it should in regular property declaration (`visible: isExpanded`).

So the question is, do I really need to explicitly tell Qt to bind property to make it work?

**Edit:** To make clear: I'm certain I don't reassign visible property anywhere. I doble checked it. And though qml size is only about 100 of lines I used ctrl+f to find any mention of visible and found none except already mentioned.
If there is more reliable way to tell what's from/ check for possible reassignments somewhere or something, please tell.

Comment: does "other stuff" or anything else assign to myId.visible and break the binding? That's the only thing I could think of. Or MyCustomItem declares its own visible property and the impl contains an error.

Comment: No, it doesn't. And If something would break the binding wouldn't it also break "hardcoded" binding too `myId.visible = Qt.binding(function() {return isExpanded})`? MyCustomItem is just an Item {} with other stuff in it. It doesn't use visible property at all inside itself. The only thing I "might" be reassigning - is item id (it has it's own internal id in qml file, but because there are two of them in my problematic qml - they have different id's assigned to them)

Comment: I do not like your attitude. You need to get used to that you do not have all knowledge in the world and if someone with experience says you simply break the binding it does mean you do it. It may be the most counter-intuitive bug in the world but hey, who designed it? Perhaps you do not fully understand the purpose of the mechanics or language you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue! Very unobvious (haven't found documented anywhere) and it fails silently.
The problem is that `MyCustomItem` contained a property with the same name of outer booleal property `isExpanded` so in this code:

```
MyCustomItem {
    id: myId
   visible: isExpanded
 // other stuff
}
```

`isExpanded` is from `MyCustomItem`. But without any indication of that. Well, now I know that this could happen and would probably spot it if it happens again but this is really counter-intuitive. What if it wasn't my item but someone else's and I didn't know that it had such property? Qt creator could've at least warned about possible ambiguities.

Comment: It isn't counter-intuitive at all, it follows the same scoping rules as just about every language. It's no different to doing this in C: `{ int a = 0; { int a = 1; int b  = a;} }` and expecting `b` to be 0.

Comment: @cmannett85 it's counter-intuitive because syntax is different. You don't see "insides" of item when you declare it. It's more like if you had (no in reality but how it looks and used) `int a = 0; Item b; b.setC(a)` It would be counter-intuitive if setC assigned to c some inner (to b) property a and not our that we know of.

Comment: Syntax is different, scoping semantics is not (at least from this pov). Qt Creator cannot warn for something that is feasible, even if it can be a pain in the neck, most of the times.

Answer (score 4):

> So the question is, do I really need to explicitly tell Qt to bind property to make it work?

Yes.

When declaring a property, you can use the binding syntax e.g. `visible: isExpanded`.  But setting a property in imperative code using normal JavaScript syntax (i.e. the assignment operator) will break any existing binding and overwrite the property's value.  If you want to explicitly set a property binding in imperative code, use the `Qt.binding()` method ([docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#binding-method)).

Although your actual problem is due to falling victim to QML's scoping rules.  Your `MyCustomItem` type has an `isExpanded` property, so when you declare:

```
MyCustomItem {
    id: myId
    visible: isExpanded
    // other stuff
}
```

You're actually binding `visible` to `MyCustomItem::isExpanded`.  So to fix just be explicit as to which `isExpanded` you are referring to:

```
Item {
    id: base
    property bool isExpanded: false
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            isExpanded = !isExpanded
            console.log(isExpanded)
            console.log(myId.visible)
        }
    }
    MyCustomItem {
        id: myId
        visible: base.isExpanded
        // other stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not the answer to my question! Look at my code and please read it again! The problem is binding syntax **DOESN'T WORK** for some reason (though imperative, using Qt.binding() does work). And I can't figure why.

Comment: @DanM. "Look at my code and please read it again!" Your code works perfectly.  Bindings don't fail (without error messages), which means you **are** breaking the binding, just not in the code you have provided.

Comment: @cmannett85 I reduced MyCustomItem code to this: http://pastebin.com/1RX015Sk
There is definitely no "visibility" changes there - and it still doesn't work.
It works with other my custom qmls, it works after imperative qt.bind, but it doesn't work out of the box. If there are any reassignments - they are hidden and implicit.

Comment: @DanM. I've spotted the issue.

Comment: @cmannett85 And also, it's not only with visible. It's happening with **ALL** properties of that item. If only visibility was the problem I could simply encapsulate myItems in Item and change Item's visible property (that works). But I also want to bind height,y and others.